# python2.7 quickfix library

Tags: python-2.7, quickfix

I am using python 2.7.

I would like to install the quickfix library (http://www.quickfixengine.org/).
The C ++ compiler (Microsoft Visual C ++ Compiler for Python 2.7) was shown as necessary for the installation of the quickfix library.

I installed the C ++ compiler and downloaded the quickfix library. However, an error is displayed.

C ++ \ Acceptor.cpp (21): fatal error C1083: Can not open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory

I can not install it.
I would be pleased if you could help me ...

Comment: Are you using Mac or Windows?

Comment: You are only compiling it now. And how are you building it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty `stdafx.h` file somewhere in your include search path and proceed with the compilation. This header file is used by some versions of the Microsoft development suite to accelerate compilation.  Many Microsoft tools would create this header file automatically - and largely empty - at the creation of a new project. What you have here is probably a residual of that tool's action.